# Vista software install failure

Tags: windows-vista

I'm trying to install an application on Vista and it fails and tells me that another installation is in process, or somthing like that.

Anyone know how to fix this?

I am not currently trying to install 2 applications, and I think an installation might have failed while i was installing a week or so ago, but I have restarted several times. I am trying to install JetBrains ReSharper 4.5.

Comment: Which application are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the following registry key and clean any entries that you find.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress
```

I have seen this problem with printer drivers where they aren't installed properly, they set the key and then you reboot. They fail install, but the key is set. They try and install then the loop repeats.